# Spring 4.2 - Dependancy Injection - http://www.springframework.org/schema/p error

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, maven-3

I'm doing a book simple example for DI where execution returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/p]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]
```

where app-context.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="provider" class="com.apress.prospring4.ch2.HelloWorldMessageProvider"/> 
    <bean id="renderer" class="com.apress.prospring4.ch2.StandardOutMessageRenderer" p:messageProvider-ref="provider"/>
</beans>
```

All prevous exercices are working fine...
External additional exercice on bean without DI works fine also...
Using Spring 4.2, Maven 3, JVM 1.8.
Any idea?

EDIT I've changed the p:notation to

```
<bean id="renderer" class="com.apress.prospring4.ch2.StandardOutMessageRenderer">
    <property name="messageProvider" ref="provider" />
</bean>
```

and removed the p namespace reference so that app now works, which is good because I'm a learning newbie there.

Nevertheless I keep wondering how to have p namespace working!
As a side note i don't see any "http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" despite I can see a "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"; Probably my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when packaging the application into a single executable Jar (worked when running directly in eclipse/IntelliJ).

The problem was the spring.schemas file was being overwritten in the META-INF folder during the packaging.

You can solve that by using the maven shade plugin, and building the jar using mvn clean package

You'll need to use the transformers to append the spring files like so (and change the main class to be your own)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>tom.lightwaverf.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```